# Ghost blog service stopped, when I restart it, there's no content

Tags: digital-ocean, ghost-blog, ghost

I've had an installation of the ghost blogging platform on a DigitalOcean server for at least a year now. Everything was working great until 2 days ago, when I realized my blog is down.
I accessed the server, and saw that the process wasn't running. I started it again, but I don't have the content anymore, and no settings were saved.

Looking into the ghost folders, I see the `/content/data` folder with all the posts and images I had, but when I start the blog (just using `node index.js`) and I go to the url in the browser, I see the blog as if it's never been configured with a user, and no data is present.

How do I restore my configuration settings, and the content I used to have ?

Comment: You could try to connect to the SQLite database and see if there are any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was a pretty stupid mistake on my side...

I was starting the server by just running index.js like this : `node index.js`
But when I initially started the ghost blog it was by running `npm start --production`

Ghost blog comes built with 2 databases - one for production use, and another for development purposes or anything else you want to play around with. When I started it in 'production mode' again I got my content and all the settings back. :)